# python mechanize form submit with hebrew chars

Tags: python, hebrew

While trying to submit a form which has some Hebrew chars, the post request seem to send gibberish instead of the Hebrew chars.

This is a snippet of the post request:

```
-----------------------------172786975114076637123207688954999633792044868004090111518
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="product[spec]"


                                    <div><p><strong>����"�:</strong> X340H21G<br/><strong>��������</strong>: ���� ������ X340H21G ����� ������� �����: X342<br/><strong>������� �����: </strong>���� ������ X340H21G ��� ������ ����� �� �� 6,000 ���� ��� ����� ����� �� 5% ����� �� ����� A4<br/><strong>����� �����</strong>: ���� ������ X340H21G ���� ������ ���� ���� ������ ����</p></div>
-----------------------------172786975114076637123207688954999633792044868004090111518
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="product[product_features_attributes][0][position]"

1
```

How do I make Mechanize send the chars in the right charset?

Thanks!!

Comment: how are you posting?

Comment: It'd help if you'd follow [ask], e.g., give a minimal code example of what you do that produces the error.